# Which is the best web server for Ruby on Rails application on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I tried it by installing Phusion passenger..Phusion passenger was succeessfully installed but while configuring it to Apache i'm facing a problem ....

So can anybody tell me what is the best websever for ruby on rails applications to host them on Ubuntu ...

Comment: While perhaps not the best for all situations, passenger is probably the easiest to configure.  If you're having configuration options with passenger, the other app servers probalby aren't going to help.

Comment: K darvidson so please tell me "what is a good webserver for hosting Ruby on rails application on ubuntu"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combination of Apache and Passenger is a very good web server for Ruby on Rails applications on Ubuntu.

1. There is very good support, on the web, from Apache, from Phusion and here on Stackoverflow.
2. Many sites are running Rails on Passenger. The technology is robust and well understood.
3. Same for Ubuntu.
4. Same for Apache, only more so.

Basically I'd say that if you are just starting out that you should go with Passenger/Apache unless you have a compelling need for some other stack. Given that you are asking the question without any other details, I'm assuming that you don't have such a compelling need.

The other thing that is true today is that there are lots of choices. You can combine Passenger, or Thin, or Mongrel, or Unicorn with Apache, or Nginx or alone, and you can mix them with Varnish or other cache. Once you have your site configured on one stack, you can move it to another without too much difficulty.

First though, you have to configure it once, and for that Passenger and Apache are a good combination on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Apache and passenger is reliable and configurable way to go. But if you just want to run single application, the zero configuration way is [passenger standalone](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html)

```
gem "passenger"
```

in your Gemfile and

```
$ passenger start -e production -p 80
```

in console should start nginx server in port 80 with production environment. It would automatically install nginx server for you.

If port 80 is not blocked by the firewall,  you can access your application from the internet by

```
http://your-server-ip-address/
```